# is there any way I can access my remote LAN using teamviewer VPN?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, vpn

Or any other VPN. The thing is

Remote host (Windows 10 Professional):

Remote LAN interface om some local subnet (i.e. 10.7.0.X).

Remote VPN interface on some other subnet  (i.e. 7.X.X.X).

My host (Windows 7 Ultimate):

VPN interface on that other subnet (i.e. 7.X.X.X).

All I have is a connection from my 7.X.X.X VPN interface to the remote host's 7.X.X.X VPN interface.

I need to access 10.7.0.X hosts on the remote LAN. It would be a piece of cake if those were routers or linux boxes but they are windows machines.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which subnet are you trying to connect the VPN to precisely?

Comment: 10.7.0.0/24. Edited the question to clarify.